# minimum number of operations(+,-,*,/,%) to represent an integer from a list of digits [1,9]

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, arithmetic, combinations, computational-complexity

We define the complexity of an integer n to be the minimum number of operations we need to represent n using only the digits 0, 1, ..., 9 (multiple times each, if necessary).

The operations allowed are addition (+), subtraction (-), multiplication (*), integer division (/, defined as the floor of normal division), and modulo operator (%, defined as a % b = a - b * (a / b)).

Examples:

The complexity of 72 is 1.
We can represent 72 using one operation as 8 * 9.

The complexity of 19 is 2.
We need at least two operations to represent 19. One representation is 5 * 5 - 6.

The complexity of 7 is 0.
We don't need any operations, since the number is already a digit.

The complexity of 4187 is 5.
We need at least five operations to represent 4187. One representation is (5 * 9 + 8) * (8 * 9 + 7).

The complexity of 14771 is 6.
We need at least six operations to represent 14771. One representation is 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 * 9 / 4 + 9

Given N, find the sum of complexities of all positive integers less than N.

1<=N<=17000

Example

For N = 100, the answer=155

For N = 417, the answer=1055

For N = 1000, the answer=3145

what I need to know is : the formula to find the answer or the process to solve the maths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the task  on the dynamically programming with very big space. 
Rough upbound of the minimum number of operations is about 12 
(17000 <9^6)

Comment: So is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Programmatically - it is simple map/reduce, IMHO

Comment: You can skype me (kotomord :) ) - I'll try to explain the solution

Comment: I don't use skype... Any other way to contact you? I need to understand the solution badly-@kotomord

Comment: kotomord82@yandex.ru - email